# How to replace a built-in vscode extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

How do you replace a built-in vscode extension?

I have developed a vscode extension that supports both printing and rendered preview of documents. Since one of the document formats it can render is Markdown, this completely subsumes the function of the built-in vs code Markdown preview extension so I would like to suppress the built-in preview and all its now redundant UI.

Why would you want to replace the built-in preview?

- Markdown isn't the only document format for which a preview is useful. There are half dozen third party previewers just for HTML and SVG.
- Doing it my way means that if you can preview it you can print it (or generate a PDF of it)
- My extension supports registration of document renderers by other extensions, so you can integrate your own document format into the preview/print infrastructure.
- You get the option to to preview in an external browser, sidestepping VS Code's inability to use multiple monitors.

I've tried hijacking its messages to redirect function. There is direct equivalence since I know what format those messages are trying to handle, but this doesn't work - it's not possible to overwrite the registration. I can't find any way to suppress the loading and I can't get in first. Suppressing loading would be ideal. If this fails to remove context menu items I can always handle the messages they generate.

A way to hijack the messages would be a good second prize, although I imagine this would send the VS Code team into a security panic ending with them deliberately breaking it.

Comment: There is a `workbench.extensions.uninstallExtension` command (see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands).  But I doubt it will work with a built-in extension.